# Ansible-Azure Image Copy across subscriptions

Tags: azure, ansible

I am quite new to ansible and Azure , I would like to know do we have a module in ansible which can copy azure image from one subscription to other ?

It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Shared Image Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries) is the official way to share VM images between subscriptions. You can use your prefeed toolkit (Azure CLI, PowerShell, etc) to automate the process in Ansible.

Comment: Hi, I went through that , but is there a way to do it ansible way ?